# How to find your Pinterest Board ID

Tags: pinterest

I'd like to fetch the ID of a Pinterest board (not the SLUG), but the numerical ID.
Would someone please be able to provide a helpful answer as to how I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

None of the documented solutions worked for me. There's a simple way though : open the developer tools of your web browser, tab `Network` and the board id is present in some of the requests. For example I have a request to url :

`https://fi.pinterest.com/_ngjs/resource/BoardCollaboratorsResource/get/?source_url=/<REDACTED>/<REDACTED>/&data={"options":{"isPrefetch":false,"board_id":"<REDACTED>"},"context":{}}&_=<REDACTED>`

Where you see the `board_id` explicitly referenced.

Answer (score 0):

However, if there is an image associated with the board, you can extract the board ID by parsing it:

For example:

```
<meta property="og:image" name="og:image" content="http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/custom_covers/200x150/426153252178994482_1392419088.jpg" data-app>
```

The important part of this is "426153252178994482", which is the board ID. This can be confirmed by looking through the source of your page for the javascript/json at the bottom which identifies the board via the URL and id in an object, but that's a bit more difficult to parse.

Comment: So what you've basically done is copied and answered and pasted it here from a few months ago...

Comment: yes brother he need help on a question,i Google it for an answer and found something helpful for him,I think every programmer should know "HOW TO GOOGLE" first it also a important part for a programmer.and For you kind of information my all answers are just copy paste

Answer (score 0):

Open board web page source.
Use this regular expression to find id in the page source.

**[0-9]{18}**

Basically a Pinterest board id has 18 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I found this way.

1. Open the developer tools of your web browser.
2. Navigate to the "Network" tab.
3. Use the filter to search for "boardID".
4. Look for requests that contain "boardID" in the URL.
5. Extract the board ID from the relevant request URL.

The URL could be like this below:

```
https://in.pinterest.com/resource/BoardToolsFeedResource/get/?source_url=/<REDACTED>/&data={"options":{"boardId":"<THIS IS YOUR BOARD ID>","orbacSubjectId":""},"context":{}}&_=<REDACTED>
```

The board ID is present within the "boardId" parameter in the URL. You can extract the board ID value from this parameter and use it as needed in your application or script.